# Unity - FPS rigid-body controller not aligning to spherical gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, rigid-bodies

I'm currently working on a fps game in which you can travel to asteroids and walk on them, currently I have gravity for those asteroids and I have a fps controller that works for all my other movement systems (swimming, floating) but translating it to the gravity of the asteroid is giving me a lot of trouble. I can get the controller to work perfectly on flat surfaces using Unity's gravity but not on the asteroid.

The current fps controller moves in the direction of the camera which means the character floats up when looking up, all my other fps controllers didn't work at all with the planet and this one is the closet I've gotten to getting it to work.

Is there anyway to fix this? I'm quite new to coding so any explanations would help me heaps!

Here's the code I'm using for the controller:

```
public Transform targetCamera;
public Rigidbody targetRigidbody;
public Transform targetBody;

public float walkSpeed = 9f;
public float runSpeed = 14f;
public float maxSpeed = 20f;
public float jumpPower = 30f;

public float extraGravity = 0;

float bodyRotationX;
float camRotationY;
Vector3 directionIntentX;
Vector3 directionIntentY;
float speed;

public bool grounded;

public float thrust = 20f;
public float forwardSwimSpeed = 45f;

private float xRotation;
private const float Sensitivity = 50f;
private const float SensitivityMultiplier = 1f;

private float desiredX;

public float dragMult = 2f;

public float rotationSmoothSpeed = 10f;


void Update()
{
    Look();
    targetRigidbody.drag = dragMult;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (targetRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
    {
        targetRigidbody.velocity = targetRigidbody.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        AddForce(Vector3.forward);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        AddForce(Vector3.back);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        AddForce(Vector3.left);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        AddForce(Vector3.right);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        AddForce(Vector3.up);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        AddForce(Vector3.down);
}

private void AddForce(Vector3 direction)
{
    float scaledForwardSwimSpeed = Time.deltaTime * forwardSwimSpeed;

    targetRigidbody.AddForce(targetCamera.transform.TransformDirection(
        direction * thrust) * scaledForwardSwimSpeed,
        ForceMode.Acceleration);
}



private void Look()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * SensitivityMultiplier;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * SensitivityMultiplier;

    Vector3 rotation = targetCamera.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    desiredX = rotation.y + mouseX;
    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
    targetCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, desiredX, 0);
}
```

And here's the first of two bits of code for the asteroid: GravityCtrl

```
public float gravity = 10f;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.GetComponent<GravityCtrl>())
    {
        other.GetComponent<GravityCtrl>().gravity = this.GetComponent<GravityOrbit>();
    }
```

Here's the second: GravityOrbit

```
public GravityOrbit gravity;
private Rigidbody rb;

public float rotationSpeed = 20f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (gravity)
    {
        Vector3 gravityUp = Vector3.zero;

        gravityUp = (transform.position - gravity.transform.position).normalized;

        Vector3 localUp = transform.up;

        Quaternion targetrotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(localUp, gravityUp) * transform.rotation;

        transform.up = Vector3.Slerp(transform.up, gravityUp, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        rb.AddForce((-gravityUp * gravity.gravity) * rb.mass);
    }
```